# A pre-filled readline

Tags: php, linux, readline

I try to have a pre-filled readline function, in PHP-CLI.
Example : ask a special folder to a user but be editable 
`PROMPT> /var/log`
The use can hit return to validate the /var/log entry or edit it after the PROMPT>

I try to put /var/log in `readline ("PROMPT> /var/log");`, but it is not editable, as it is a prompt.
I would like to have readline to accept to use the keyboard arrows to edit the data.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like the PHP readline API has this option.

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is available in the underlying GNU readline library. Is it?

Comment: I don't see anything at http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC23 that would do it

Comment: I see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.readline-info.php which can set a variable "line_buffer" but I am not able to use it

Comment: if `readline_info('line_buffer', '/var/log')` doesn't do it, then it probably can't be done.

Comment: OK, I will develop my own readline version (or doing something else). Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with any shell I know of. This is normally solved by displaying the default value and if the user doesn't enter anything the program continues with the default value. Consider the following example from `aptitude upgrade`:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

The user knows the available options and the `Y` is in uppercase and therefor the default value. Of course you can extend this to make it even more clear to your user. Maybe something along the lines:

```
Do you want to continue? [y/n] [default is y]
```

There are endless approaches to solve this.

Your program is definitely doing something before outputting `/var/log` to the prompt, so simply ask the user. I can highly recommend [Symfony2 Console](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/console/introduction.html) which makes tasks like this as easy a cycling.